# Vue.js transition and transition-group animations not working

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, css-transitions

I have a Vue 2 Carousel component, with Slide child components generated using `v-for`. Slides are displayed and hidden using `v-show`. I cannot get CSS `transition`s between Slides to work.

I tried wrapping the Slides in `<transition>` but `mode=out-in` does nothing and I end up with two Slides in the Carousel during transition, one fading in, the other out. When I wrap the Slides in a `<transition-group>`, CSS `transition`s don't show at all, Slides are just replaced.

I looked at [transitioning between components](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#Transitioning-Between-Components), but Slides are generated based on a list of links from an API and I don't see a way of combining dynamic generation with this solution.

Here's a [JSFiddle with the issue](https://jsfiddle.net/aleks_s/pzbaf3pb/1/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not intend to crossfade the images (i.e. only one image is actually on the screen at any given point of time), you can restructure your code such as only a single `<Slide>` component is rendered at a single time. You simply assign a unique key that is dynamically updated, e.g. your `active` data of the slider component.

Your template will now look like this:

```
<div class="carousel-wrapper" id="promotions">
    <transition name="component-fade" mode="out-in">
        <!-- Bind image url dynamically, bind key to active index -->
        <Slide class="slide" :url="imageUrl" :key="active"></Slide>
    </transition>
</div>
```

The `imageUrl` is simply a computed property that returns the image URL by index:

```
imageUrl() {
    return this.list[this.active].url;
}
```

The `Slide` component should be as "dumb" as we need it to: in this case, it simply receives the dynamically-bound image URL and nothing more:

```
<div>
    <img :src="url" class="image">
</div>
```

Note:

- you should use a transition duration that is equal to, or shorter than, the time interval of your `active` property updates. In your original code the slides are cycled ever 3s but the transition-duration is set to 4s, leading to really janky transitions
- the solution will be more complicated if you want a crossfade animation.

Here is a proof-of-concept example:

```js
Vue.component('Slide', {
  template: `
 <div>
  <img :src="url" class="image">
 </div>`,
  props: ['url']
});

Vue.component('component-2', {
  template: `<div>
                    <p>component 2</p>
                 </div>`
});

new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  template: `
  <div class="carousel-wrapper" id="promotions">
  <transition name="component-fade" mode="out-in">
   <Slide class="slide" :url="imageUrl" :key="active">
   </Slide>
  </transition>
  </div>`,
  data() {
    return {
      list: [{
          url: 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/572741/pexels-photo-572741.jpeg'
        },
        {
          url: 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/575739/pexels-photo-575739.jpeg'
        },
        {
          url: 'https://static.pexels.com/photos/576832/pexels-photo-576832.jpeg'
        }
      ],
      active: 0
    }
  },
  computed: {
    numberOfSlides() {
      return this.list.length - 1
    },
    imageUrl() {
      return this.list[this.active].url;
    }
  },
  created() {
    this.rotate()
  },
  methods: {
    moveSlide(event) {
      this.active = event.srcElement.dataset.slide
      this.list.forEach(el => {
        el.active = false
      })
      this.list[event.srcElement.dataset.slide].active = true
    },
    rotate() {
      if (this.active < this.numberOfSlides) {
        this.active = this.active + 1
      } else {
        this.active = 0
      }
      let _this = this
      setTimeout(_this.rotate, 3000)
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.carousel-wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

.carousel {}

.dots {
  max-width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 2em;
  z-index: 1;
}

.dot {
  height: 1em;
  width: 1em;
  margin: 0 1em 0 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: red;
}

.component-fade-enter-active,
.component-fade-leave-active {
  transition: opacity 1s ease;
}

.component-fade-enter,
.component-fade-leave-to {
  opacity: 0;
}

.slide {
  width: 100%;
  height: 650px;
}

.image {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 650px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.4.4/vue.min.js"></script>
<div id="example">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because you do not need to use `v-show`.

You should just use `<transition name="slide-fade"><slides></slides></transition>` and then define your transition in the CSS.

You should see this [doc](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/transitions.html#CSS-Transitions), it worked for me.